# Replacing string with Regex with start and end tags with Java replace function

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a mathematical formulas string like this.

```
(##type## * 2) + 5 + ##component## + ##param##
```

After replacing, I want to get like this.

```
((value.type) * 2) + 5 + (value.component) + (value.param)
```

I will always add the "value." string to the begining of the parameters and add both side (). How can i do this?

Comment: Why don't you put it in a method and pass in the parameters, and put the variables in the mathematical function?

Comment: What did you try? Did you research regex capture groups?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47265834/4016500

Answer (score 4):

```
String test = "(##type## * 2) + 5 + ##component## + ##param##";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("##(.*?)##", "(value.$1)"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by chaining `replaceAll` methods, e.g.:

```
class Value {
    String type;
    String component;
    String param;
    //Getters and setters
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "(##type## * 2) + 5 + ##component## + ##param##";
    Value value = new Value();
    value.type = "a";
    value.component = "b";
    value.param = "c";
    s = s.replace("##type##", value.type).replaceAll("##component##", value.component).replaceAll("##param##",
            value.param);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: I think it is true already but best answer is this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47265834/4016500